# Recreate Outlook @ AutoComplete to display Email Context in a c# Textbox

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface

i want to recreate the Outlook function, that lets you insert EMail Users using @ in the Mail Body. I want to do this in C# with the .Net Windows Textboxes. And i don't know where to start with this... Any suggestions?